# Query for where not exists with count

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fetching customers randomly based from the 2 tables I have,

```
customer
========
id
first_name
surname
country

call_log
====
id
customer_id #FK
create_by
create_datetime
status (status for No answer is 7)
```

As of now, I need to exclude customer that has 2 count of No answer status in the call logs. I have tried this

```
SELECT
    customer.id, 
    customer.first_name,
    customer.country
FROM
    customer
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 #I dont know what I should do here
        FROM 
            call_log
        WHERE
            call_log.customer_id = customer.id AND
            call_log.status = 7 AND #no answer
            call_log.create_datetime BETWEEN '2015-10-06 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-06 23:59:59'
    )
```

Any help is very much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the query you provided?

Comment: SELECT 1 is perfectly fine in the NOT EXISTS sub-select. (The question is if a row exists or not.)

Comment: I need to get customer that has no 2 no answer from the call_log within the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the sub-select return the number of no's instead.

```
SELECT
    customer.id, 
    customer.first_name,
    customer.country
FROM
    customer
WHERE (SELECT count(*)
       FROM call_log
       WHERE call_log.customer_id = customer.id AND
             call_log.status = 7 AND #no answer
             call_log.create_datetime BETWEEN '2015-10-06 00:00:00'
                                          AND '2015-10-06 23:59:59') < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
    customer.id, 
    customer.first_name,
    customer.country
FROM
    customer
WHERE (SELECT count(*)
       FROM call_log
       WHERE call_log.customer_id = customer.id AND
             call_log.status = 7 AND #no answer
             call_log.create_datetime BETWEEN '2015-10-06 00:00:00'
                                          AND '2015-10-06 23:59:59') < 2

Comment: Very, very similar to my answer, but less formatted, later, and no description at all.